# Windows 10 - Problem using xfce4-terminal emulator and keyboard shortcuts

Tags: windows, shortcut-keys, xfce

I'm currently using an xfce4-terminal (not desktop) using a virtual machine on my Windows 10. Something annoying is that I am not able to use shortcuts involving the Windows key to fastly move windows as on Windows 10 (for example, Windows+LeftArrow is moving the current window to the left). So I tried to edit the config file at `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm` to see if I can configure such shortcuts. I am able, for example, to bind the "Left" shortcut to do a simple "copy" and it works great by adding the following line :

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/copy" "<Super>Left")
```

It would be great if, instead of the "copy" action, there was an action like "move-window-left". Here is my trouble : I'm not able to find any action of this type. I haven't find any list of possible "Actions" for terminal keyboard-shortcuts, is there one somewhere? Otherwise, is there a way to use custom shortcuts (maybe calling a python script to do what I want for ex)?

Finally, I think the simplest way to use Windows-shortcuts would be that the xfce4-terminal was not able to recognize the Super key when I'm pressing it (what I mean is when using "xev", push down the Super key would do absolutely nothing so my Windows 10 would interpret it instead of the linux terminal). But I'm afraid that it's not possible.. Any ideas?